# Compilation error using string::pop_back()

Tags: c++, string, c++11, substring, stdstring

I am trying to remove last character of string. Since I am using c++11 I am using `pop_back()`:

```
std::string ipAddresses = response.substr(response.find_first_of(",")+1);
responseVector.push_back( ipAddresses.pop_back() );
```

For some reason I am getting compilation error:

```
 error: invalid use of void expression
 responseVector.push_back( ipAddresses.pop_back() );
```

Could someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: pop_back doesn’t return the popped item. You need to call back() first and then pop it.

Comment: I want to remove last character from ipAddresses string

Comment: [`pop_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) returns `void`

Comment: You are trying to do **two** things. Get the last character, and remove the last character. But pop_back does only one of these things.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/pop_back/ according to the example shown here my code should be fine

Comment: ipAddresses.pop_back() returns void.  Review the reference again.  The  push_back of 'void' into responseVector is the error.

Comment: Generic hint: cplusplus.com is considered an inferior resource...

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it in two steps:

```
responseVector.push_back( ipAddresses.back() );
ipAddresses.pop_back();
```

Comment: This does not seem to address OP’s question

Comment: Why not? It fixes OP's compilation problem and keep the wanted functionality.

Comment: @Sailanarmo quite contrary, it seems to address OP's question well.

Comment: If a function `void v()` is used with `bool push_back(char)` like this:  `push_back(v());` it will fail with the warning.  That's what the OP is doing, and what Adrian W addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something simple to remove the last character of a *string*:

```
const size_t length(ipAddresses.length());
if (length > 0)
{
  ipAddresses.erase((length - 1), 1);
}
```

The above code gets the length of the string.
If string has at least one character, erase the last character.
Note, the position is 0-based, thus the subtraction of 1.

Comment: You can't initialize `size_t` with `std::string`. That should be `const size_t length(ipAddresses.length());` or, more C++1x-ish `auto const length(ipAddresses.length());`. The `count` parameter to `erase()` can be omitted, as the default value erases to the end of the string.

Comment: Good catch!  Missed that `length` method.